# Gem features doesn't properly load actual gem code

Tags: ruby, load, cucumber, rubygems

I've got a gem with cukes and specs that extend RSpec subjects.

All specs runs fine but the features doesn't seem to properly load the current gem code. Seems partially there though.

The gem is at https://github.com/ZenCocoon/rspec-subject-extensions

Note: New to cucumber, I might have skipped something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `rspec` is being launched as a separate process. The spec file you're defining in your Cucumber feature does not require these extensions and so they won't be made available. The reason it's working in your RSpec tests is because you *do* require these extensions.

To fix this, you can add one line to the top of your Cucumber feature to require the `rspec/subject/extensions.rb` file:

```
Given a file named "example_spec.rb" with:
"""
  require 'rspec/subject/extensions'

  class Movie
    def ratings
      [9, 7, 9]
    end
  end

  describe Movie do
    each(:rating) { should be_an(Integer) }
  end
"""
```

This will fix the problem.